# Python Lists Comparison & Print

Tags: python, list

I have two lists:

```
chars = ["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"];
```

and

```
cipher = ["AA","AB","AC","AD","AE","AF","BA","BB","BC","BD","BE","BF","CA","CB","CC","CD","CE","CF","DA","DB","DC","DD","DE","DF","EA","EB","EC","ED","EE","EF","FA","FB","FC","FD","FE","FF"];
```

I want it so that if a user inputs a line of text, it compares the text in chars to the cipher so that, for example, the fifth element of chars ("4") corresponds to the fifth element in cipher ("AE"), and prints that out. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you want a [dictionary](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) (another [link](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#typesmapping)):

```
d = dict(zip(chars,cipher))
```

Then, to to get the cipher from the character, you'd do:

```
print d[whatever_char]  #prints the cipher associated with that character
```